# Elasticsearch proper way to escape spaces, ? doesn't work in all scenarios

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to get searching with spaces to work properly in elasticsearch but having a ton of trouble getting it to behave the same way as it does on another field.

I have two fields, `Name` and `Addresses.First().Line1` that I want to be able to search and preserve spaces in the search. For instance, searching for `Bob Smi*` would return `Bob Smith` but not just `Bob`.

This is working for my Name field by doing a query string search with the space replaced with `?`. I'm also doing a wildcard so my final query is `*bob?smi*`.

However, when I try to also search by line1, I get no results. E.g. `*4800*` returns a record with line1 like `4800 Street`, but when I do the same transformation with `4800 street` to get `*4800?street*`, I get no results.

Below is my query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*4800?Street*",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "addresses.line1"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns no result.

Why would `*bob?smi*` return result with name `Bob Smith` but `*4800?street*` not return result with line item `4800 street`?

Below is how both fields are set up in the index:

```
.Text(smd => smd.Name(c => c.Name).Analyzer(ElasticIndexCreator.SortAnalyzer).Fielddata())

.Nested<Address>(nomd => nomd.Name(p => p.PrimaryAddress).Properties(MapAddressProperties))

//from MapAddressProperties()

.Text(smd2 => smd2.Name(x => x.Line1).Analyzer(ElasticIndexCreator.SortAnalyzer).Fielddata())
```

Mappings in elastic:

```
"name": {
    "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
    }
}
"addresses": {
    "line1": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
    },
 }
```

Is there some other, better way to escape a space in an elasticsearch querystring? I've also tried `\\` and `\\\\` (in C# evaluates to `\\`) instead of the `?` to no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at using a match phrase or match phrase prefix query? That seems to be more in line with what you want, considering the use cases you've presented so far: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: That seems to only work for one field. I have many fields I'm searching through, this is just an example of 2 of them.

Comment: I've read your post several times, but I am not sure I understand what is the requirement here. Search with spaces in it but at the same time you are trying with `?`? For your reference, to search `4800 street` exactly as you see it, you need to use `"query": "\"4800 street\""`. Double quotes surrounding the text so that it's searched exactly like that.

Comment: And regarding `*bob?smi*`, what is the exact query and document that matches? Because the examples you provided - a `name` of `Bob Smith` and a search for `*bob?smi*` WILL NOT return a match.

Comment: Your document and `query_string` will return something if you search for `"query": "*Bob?Smi*"` inside `name.keyword`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan searching for `"\"4800 street\""` returned the same type of results, some for `4800` some for `street`

Comment: @AndreiStefan the exact query and result is as shown. Another example: searching for `*abc?company*` returns a result with name `ABC Company`.  the `?` is intended to be a stand-in for "any character" and seems to work fine for the name field

Comment: Please, provide a standalone simplified example (with complete mapping, data and a query) in a `gist` that demonstrates that `"\"4800 street\""` matches `address.line1: street`.

Comment: I believe my example is pretty clear. I'm searching two fields that have the same type of mapping. I'm using query string because i have many fields i'm searching at once. Searching the `name` field gives me proper results when there are spaces in the query, searching `addresses.line1` does not. There must be some difference in the way these fields are created or interpreted, but I can find no evidence that there is such a difference.

Comment: And I'm telling you that I tested this with the mapping and the documents _I assumed_ you have. I cannot reproduce your statements. Sorry about that. Unless you provide that test I asked for, I cannot help you further. One more detail: I have tested this in the Dev Tools console (meaning no C# code anywhere). First we need to clear out the things from the usual `curl` query the ES cluster receives and not what your code is doing.

Comment: The only reason I can come up with is that it is somehow related to the fact that the field is nested. If you could provide the gist requested by @AndreiStefan I could test it out.

Comment: @AndreiStefan and @slinzerthegod I'm not sure what more information you need, I've provided the mapping and a simplified query already. How do i get a `gist` as you mention?

Comment: @DLeh this is gist: https://gist.github.com/. In it you can add REST commands that you used to test this. It should include the creation of an index and its mapping, some simple test data, and some queries that show us what doesn't work and what should work.

Comment: Here is a beginning that begins to illustrate my problem. I will continue to add more examples with other things i've tried. https://gist.github.com/DrLeh/4288c26a112479e400865d04f99723a1

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the correct setup after tons of time experimenting. The configuration that worked for me was as follows:

1. Use Text with Field Data in the columns
2. Search using QueryString with wildcard placeholders, replacing spaces with `?` e.g. `bob smith` is entered, query elastic with `*bob?smith*`
3. **Use Nested queries for child objects**. Oddly, `addresses.line1` will return data when searching for say `4800` but not when trying to do `*4800?street*`. Using a nested query allows this to function properly .

From what I hear, having to use field data is very memory intensive, and having to use wildcards is very time intensive, so this is probably not an optimal solution but it's the only one I've found. If there is another better way to do this, please enlighten me.

Example queries in C# using Nest:

```
var query = Query<Student>.QueryString(qs => qs
                .Fields(f => f
                .Field(c => c.Name)
                //.Field(c => c.PrimaryAddress.Line1) //this doesn't work
                )
                .Query(testCase.Term)
            );

query |= Query<Student>.Nested(n => n
        .Path(p => p.Addresses)
            .Query(q => q
                .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .Fields(f => f.Field(c => c.Addresses.First().Line1))
                        .Query(testCase.Term)
                    )
            )
        );
```

Example Mapping:

```
.Map<Student>(s => s.Properties(p => p
    .Text(t => t.Name(z => z.Name).Fielddata())
    .Nested<StudentAddress>(n => n
        .Name(ap => ap.Addresses)
        .Properties(ap => ap.Text(t => t.Name(z => z.Line1).Fielddata())
    )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `addresses.line1.keyword` (that is, try the `keyword` multi-field that you defined for `addresses.line1`) in <s>the `fields` parameter</s> a [term-level wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html):

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "addresses.line1.keyword": {
                "wildcard": "*4800 street*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Per [Elasticsearch documentation on full-text wildcard searches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards), if you search against `addresses.line1` (whose type is `text` so full-text search rules apply), the search will be performed against each term analyzed out of the field, that is, once against `4800` and again against `street`, none of which would match your `*4800?street*` wildcard.  The `addresses.line1.keyword` multi-field contains the original `4800 street` value, and should match your query pattern using a term-level wildcard query.

---

By the way, a minor nit: the mapping type definition itself seems incomplete for the `addresses` field.  You said it is:

```
"addresses": {
    "line1": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
    },
}
```

But IMHO it should instead be:

```
"addresses": {
    "properties": {
        "line1": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```